# php regex question for matching google searchterms in url

Tags: php, regex

im finding searchwords from google request urls.
im using

```
preg_match("/[q=](.*?)[&]/", $requesturl, $match);
```

but it fails when the 'q' parameter is the last parameter of the string.

so i need to fetch everything that comes after 'q=', but the match must stop IF it finds '&'

how to do that?

EDIT:
I eventually landed on this for matching google request url: 
    /[?&]q=([^&]+)/
Because sometimes they have a param that ends with q. like 'aq=0'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need `/q=([^&]+)/`. The trick is to match everything except `&` in the query.**

To build on your query, this is a slightly modified version that will (almost) do the trick, and it's the closest to what you have there: `/q=(.*?)(&|$)/`. It puts the `q=` out of the brackets, because inside the brackets it will match *either* of them, not both together, and at the end you need to match either `&` or the end of the string (`$`). There are, though, a few problems with this:

1. sometimes you will have an extra `&` at the end of the match; you don't need it. To solve this problem you can use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) query: `(?=&|$)`
2. it introduces an extra group at the end (not necessarily bad, but can be avoided) -- actually, this is fixed by 1.

So, if you want a slightly longer query to expand what you have there, here it is: `/q=(.*?)(?=&|$)/`

Comment: +1 for posting the correct one before I had a chance to correct mine :)

Comment: it doesnt match it for me :/
here is one string it should match:
`http://www.google.no/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CHMQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iphonedeksler.no%2Fiphone-4-deksel%2F&rct=j&q=deksel%20til%20iphone%204&ei=eMVOTpDfBI7DtAaA4cTLBw&usg=AFQjCNEJ2ZqJdBeUw4DcgETEPr0z3z18NA`
and another it should match:
`http://www.google.no/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CHMQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iphonedeksler.no%2Fiphone-4-deksel%2F&rct=j&&ei=eMVOTpDfBI7DtAaA4cTLBw&usg=AFQjCNEJ2ZqJdBeUw4DcgETEPr0z3z18NA&q=deksel%20til%20iphone%204`.. but none of the things in this thread so far match.

Comment: @Kristian Rafteseth strange, it works in my regexr http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ . It should work with preg_match, I'll try it in codepad.

Comment: Strange thing. It gave me an error in codepad, but works in ideone: http://ideone.com/IWPcP

Comment: omg im sorry, i f*cked up somewhere else in my code. thanks alot for the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match("/q=([^&]+)/", $requesturl, $match);
```

A little explaining:

- `[q=]` will search for **either** `q` or `=`, but not one after another.
- `[&]` is not needed as there is only one character. `&` is fine.
- the `?` operator in regex tells it to match **0 or 1** occurrences of the ** preceding** character.
- `[^&]` will tell it to match any character **except** for `&`. Which means you'll get all the query string until it hits &.